# confused about how listview and listadapter works

Tags: android, listview, crash, listadapter

I'm trying to make a very simple listview just to learn.  When I set the adapter on the listview(accessed from xml), the app crashes, but when I just put setAdapter without putting it behind a listview, the listview works.  I'm running it on Samsung Galaxy s3 smartphone.

Here are my codes

ListviewAndroidExample.java(Even when I put setContentView to  R.layout.activity_main after onCreate, it crashes)

```
 package com.example.listview;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class ListViewAndroidExample extends ListActivity {

        ListView list;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             String[] Home = {
                    "BEDROOM",
                    "BATHROOM",
                    "KITCHEN",
                    "WASHROOMS",
                    "BASEMENT"};
            ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Home);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);


}}
```

My xml file(activity_main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingLeft="8dp"
     android:paddingRight="8dp">

 <ListView android:id="@+id/mylist"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#00FF00"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:divider="#FFCC00"
           android:dividerHeight="4px"/> 
           android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>     
</LinearLayout>
```

Please also tell me how to make a long toast which will say which(position) listitem was clicked, on clicking a listitem.

Comment: Ask your "item click" question in a separate thread, because the question is not related to the title and this would cause people to down-vote your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you extend ListActivity, you'll have to put an XML listview in your layout file.

And the ListView's id should be exactly: **"@android:id/list"**

That's how Android finds the list layout.

You might want to read [ListActivity and Custom Layout](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) to become more familiar with the concept.

*So change your layout from:*

```
android:id="@+id/listView1"
```

*To:*

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

### **EDIT :**

> Please also tell me how to make a long toast which will say
>   which(position) listitem was clicked, on clicking a listitem.

OK, use this for item click.

```
your_listview_object.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
        Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Clicked on list item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

### **EDIT 2:**

If you are new to Android I suggest you try and master using ListView in a simple activity that `extends Activity` first, and then go for `extends ListActivity` option.

Comment: Please tell me how to write the code in the main activity about getting the listview(e.g. "ListView listview=(ListView)findViewBy...."

Comment: But vogella doesn't use the same android Id you suggested.  Why does he convert the string array into arraylist. Some other people don't do this.  And he uses stablearrayadapter.  Why is this?

Comment: Thank you folks.  Now it is working!!!. I added setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) after onCreate, used extends Activity and didn't use the android id.  Thank you very much folks, these fine points are not mentioned in developer.android.com. Thank you

Comment: Welcome. Stay hungry :)

Answer (score 1):

as you are extending list activity,which is default & provided by android,you have to use

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

instead of

```
@+id/mylist
```